# No me muestra bd en consola

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Buenas tardes

La pregunta es sencilla, no se que tanto sea la respuesta

Tengo estas bases de datos en `phpmyadmin`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al consultarlas por consola, sólo me muestra estas:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe por qué no me muestra las otras `bases de datos`?

Comment: Pues a simple pareciera que el usuario con el que ingresas por medio de phpmyadmin tiene permisos sobre todas las bases de datos mientras que el que usas por consola solo tiene permiso para trabajar sobre la base de datos test

Comment: Hola Jorius. Gracias por la respuesta. ¿Sabes como puedo ver y resolver el tema de los usuarios?

Answer (score 2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me parece recordar que cuando abres phpmyadmin a la derecha puedes encontrar el usuario con el que te has logueado, ahora comprueba que a la hora de conectarte vía cli estés entrando con el mismo usuario.